# Why did my African Dwarf Frog repeatedly bang his head against the wall?

Tags: death, frogs

I had two African Dwarf frogs, and four neon tetras which are extremely calm fish. Then around 9:30 at night, one of my frogs just started banging his head against the side of the fish tank. My fish weren't bothering him, and the frog was on the opposite side of the fish tank. I was watching them for awhile, and out of nowhere he started doing that. He did die, but I am wondering why he would have done that, if nothing was even bothering him. I bought another one the next day, and he is doing very well.

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but is the frog one that might be aggressive towards other frogs?  I know some fish that are peaceful, except towards conspecifics to the point that they will attack their own reflection on the glass.

Comment: @Gary The frog never really seemed aggressive, he was just always very hyper. The two frogs did get along for a few days, then the one just went crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have several (4) and I often see them sort of obliviously swimming into the wall or objects or each other. It does not appear to be with aggressive intent but they make quick snappy movements and don't necessarily account for bumping things.

Pretty much any time they need air they shoot up almost as fast as they can and then back down again usually hitting into the ground at the same speed. After hitting the ground or a object they will continue to try to move forward for another 2-3 kicks sort of ram-sliding themselves along the surface.

It's important to note that their small weight makes this slamming relatively harmless much like a person bumping into a wall while walking.

<strike>One other thing that could cause odd behavior would be some kind of disease but I highly doubt that is the case here.</strike>

Edit: Did not see that he died - it was probably erratic behavior as a result of being ill and or in unsuitable conditions, and or system shock.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but what he was doing doesn't seem to be normal to me. He was just sitting at the bottom of the fish tank, and slamming his head into the side.

Comment: Has he done it since with a short interval between head slams? (I added a little that I forgot to mention with regard to what I see daily)

Comment: He died afterwards because he was doing it so hard.

Comment: Ah. Even so I don't think that was the cause. He was probably acting eccentrically as a result of perhaps being ill. Like I said, they can't actually hit into things hard enough or with enough force to cause any actual damage (unless its a sharp object).